# NestJS validate total size of uploaded files

Tags: validation, nestjs, multer, attachment, max-size

I'm trying to upload a bunch of attachments in my NestJS project. It's an array of multiple files and uploaded like so

```
  @Post('/text')
  async addText(@UploadedFiles() files){
    console.log ("The files", files)
  }
```

How do I ensure that the total size of the all the attachments do not exceed say 5MB? Is there a way to validate all the files?

Answer (score 0):

in [document](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#file-validation) has mention this validation, or you can use Multer config to validate the size in your module like this:

```
  imports: [
MulterModule.registerAsync({
  useFactory: () => ({
    // other config
    limits: {
      fileSize: parseInt(process.env.MAX_SIZE_PER_FILE_UPLOAD),
      files: parseInt(process.env.MAX_NUMBER_FILE_UPLOAD),
    },
  }),
}),
//other code
]
```